# Optional Imports in ES2015 node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6

Is there a way using ES2015 (using the `import` syntax) to import a module only if it exists?

For example, I want to use a natively-compiled module if it can be installed, but fallback to a pure-js module if it fails for any reason.

I had assumed the following would work:

```
let crc32;
try {
  import Sse4Crc32 from 'sse4_crc32';
  crc32 = Sse4Crc32.calculate;
} catch (e) {
  import crcJs from 'crc';
  crc32 = crcJs;
}
```

However it gives the error `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`. Is there a way to do this using the `import` syntax in ES2015?

Comment: See also [*How can I conditionally import an ES6 module?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible in ES2015, imports only work at the top level. Since you're using node I would use require instead in this case.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks! I'll mark as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 2):

This is beyond old, but if anyone wants to do this nowadays it is possible through [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const a = await import("this does not exist");
  } catch {
    console.log("Caught");
  }
})();
```