# Prevent emitting certain code when using webpack to deploy Electron app for the web

Tags: typescript, webpack, gulp, electron

I have a Electron-based app written in TypeScript. To bundle the code I am running webpack in my gulpfile which can either target Electron or the browser of course. The respective configuration looks as follows:

```
const appCompile = gulp.src(`${sourceFolder}/Typescript/Main.ts`)
    .pipe(webpackStream({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    loaders: ["babel-loader", "ts-loader"],
                    exclude: [/node_modules/]
                },
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: ["Source/Typescript", "node_modules"],
            extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
        },
        output: {
            filename: "Bundle.js"
        },
        mode: buildConfiguration.isDevelopment ? "development" : "production",
        externals: externals,
        target: targetPlatform.isWeb ? "web" : "electron-renderer",
        devtool: buildConfiguration.isDevelopment ? "source-map" : "none"
    }, webpack))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dest));
```

Currently I have some lines of code only meant to be executed in development mode running locally in Electrons renderer (not main!) process (since it includes some low-level fs code). Is there any way to prevent emitting those lines/calls when running webpack to deploy for the web? Something like global constants for statements like `if (isElectron) { doSomethingLocally(); }`.

**EDIT**: Especially imports like `import * as fs from "fs";` error as expected when packing for the web instead of Electron. Even though I can use a helper like `const isElectron = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Electron") !== -1;` this won't help me to "conditionally import".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has `node` configuration object, where you can tell it [what to do with built-in node modules and objects](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#other-node-core-libraries) when target is `web`.

For example, if you want `import * as fs from "fs";` to result in `fs` being `undefined`, you can try adding this line to webpack config:

```
node: targetPlatform.isWeb ? {fs: 'empty'} : undefined,
```

Then, at runtime, you can check the result and avoid using `fs` methods if they are undefined:

```
import * as fs from "fs";

if (fs.writeFile) {
}
```

Comment: With your suggested solution it is being successfully transpiled but the browser still throws an exception when trying to call methods like `fs.writeFile`. The `fs` object seems to be neither null, false or undefined.

Comment: In this case`fs` is empty object, `{}`. I updated the answer. You can also check it like this `if (Object.keys(fs).length !== 0) {}`

Comment: I just came across about an even better solution using proper ES6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543835/796036 - With this approach I can encapsulate all critical code in one module that I can conditionally import without the need to manually add all used Node modules to the webpack config. Thank you nonetheless.