# webpack vuejs/ How to import a module only in Dev mode and ignore it in production mode?

Tags: vue.js, mocking, axios

In this [simple vuejs application](https://github.com/duongphuhiep/vue-vierge-app), I use [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) to mock all the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) request from my application.

All the mock is in the javascript module [`tests/mock/api.js`](https://github.com/duongphuhiep/vue-vierge-app/blob/master/tests/mock/api.js). In order to use them, I will have to import them in [`main.js`](https://github.com/duongphuhiep/vue-vierge-app/blob/master/src/main.js#L4)

```
import "../tests/mock/api";
```

It works well in Dev mode (`npm run serve`). However, I don't want this import in Production mode (`npm run build`). Is there a way to tell webpack ignore this line of import in `main.js` when we make `npm run build`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```js
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') require("../tests/mock/api");
```

See more in [How can I conditionally import an ES6 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module/43591970)

Comment: it work, the mock module isn't included in the bunk with `npm run build`. thank you

Comment: Thank.Its super simple and useful

Comment: why it doesn't work with `process.env.VUE_LOAD_MOCK`?