# Import Only Static Variable from ES6 module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, import

I have a file common.js which contains the common variables and methods used on my App, such as a nav-bar module (nav-bar.js), and some others.

Generally, every module on my app will need to import the whole common.js module, except from login module. This one just need one of the contants defined on common.js.

If I used named imports to do something like:

```
$ import {RestURL} from "./common";
```

I realize that, yes, I can use RestURL const inside my login module, but all modules imported in common.js are imported as well, including the nav-bar module, which execute code that I do not want to be executed.

I wonder... Is there anyway to import ONLY the corresponding variable, RestURL, like a static variable, without running all the common.js code, that is, without importing all modules imported inside common.js file such as nav-bar.js module?

Thank you!!!

```
// -- common.js ---------------------------------------------------
import '../inc/nav-bar';        // NAV-BAR JS

export const RestURL = {
    login:          '/services/b2b/v2/login',
}
// -- end of common.js module -------------------------------------



// -- login.js ----------------------------------------------------
import {RestURL} from "./common";

console.log(RestURL.login);
// -- end of login.js module --------------------------------------
```

I need to use RestURL const inside login.js module, but I do not want nav-bar.js to be imported, since there is code inside it that I do not need to be exectuted when loading login.js. With the named import approach I manage to access the const RestURL, but the nav-bar module is loaded as well... :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module

Comment: Check out `JavaScript code splitting`

Comment: @MonicaAcha Thank you, I hope the conditial imports will be soonly implemented, I think it is a must!...:)

Comment: @NinoFiliu Thak you very much but I think the link is broken....:|

Comment: @ÁngelBlanco what link? I just recommended you to do a bit of research on JavaScript code splitting

Comment: Uppss...ok! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break the modules into two and import in both the modules.

```
// -- const.js ---------------------------------------------------

export const RestURL = {
    login:          '/services/b2b/v2/login',
}
// -- end of const.js module -------------------------------------


// -- common.js ---------------------------------------------------
import '../inc/nav-bar';        // NAV-BAR JS
import {RestURL} from './const.js'

// -- end of common.js module -------------------------------------




// -- login.js ----------------------------------------------------
import {RestURL} from './const.js'

console.log(RestURL.login);
// -- end of login.js module ----
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for now this is the best approach, if I only need this part of the code I can include it as a independent module... :)