# Is there a way to use SCSS theme styling on component-level in NextJS with next-themes?

Tags: sass, next.js, components, themes, scss-mixins

For my (NextJS) app I try to implement theme styling using SCSS and Next-Themes.
When I use my theme mixin on a global level it works, but on component-level it will not work. 
For the theme setting I use [this scss method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63221870/12084106) and I use [Next-Themes](https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes) to toggle between the themes.

**next.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path')
    
module.exports = {
 sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
    },
 }
```

**_app.js page:**

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes'

import '../styles/globals.scss';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ThemeProvider attribute="class" disableTransitionOnChange>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

**Layout component:**

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Header from '../Header';
import Footer from '../Footer';

import styles from './Layout.module.scss';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>My title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <main className={styles.main}>    
          {children}
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </div>      
    </>
  )
}
```

**My theme variables in _variables.scss:**

```
/* Light Theme Colors */
$color-bg-light: #f2f2f2;
$color-text-light: black;
$color-link-light: #002fff;

/* Dark Theme Colors */
$color-bg-dark: #001329;
$color-text-dark: white;
$color-link-dark: #64ff00;
```

**_themes.scss:**

```
@import './variables';

$themes: (
  dark: (
    'text-color': $color-text-dark,
    'bg-color': $color-bg-dark,
    'link-color': $color-link-dark
  ),
  light: (
    'text-color': $color-text-light,
    'bg-color': $color-bg-light,
    'link-color': $color-link-light    
  )
);

@mixin theme() {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {
    $theme-map: $map !global;
    .#{$theme} & {
      @content;
    }
  }
  $theme-map: null !global;
}

@function theme-get($key) {
  @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}
```

**ThemeSwitch component:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';

import styles from './ThemeSwitch.module.scss';

export default function ThemeSwitch() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme()

  // useEffect only runs on the client, so now we can safely show the UI
  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true)
  }, [])

  if (!mounted) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.switch}>
          The current theme is: {theme}
        <button onClick={() => setTheme('light')}>Light Mode</button>
        <button onClick={() => setTheme('dark')}>Dark Mode</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
};
```

**The use of the theme mixin within globals.scss is working:**

```
@import 'variables.scss';
@import 'themes.scss';

html,
body {
  @include theme() {
    color: theme-get('text-color');
    background-color: theme-get('bg-color');
  }
}

a {
@include theme() {
    color: theme-get('link-color');
  }
}
```

**But on component-level it is not working.** 
**E.g., Footer.module.scss:**

```
@import '../../styles/variables';
@import '../../styles/mixins';
@import '../../styles/themes';

.footer {
 
  p {
    font-size: $font-size--small;
  }

  a {
    @include theme() {
      color: theme-get('link-color');       
    }
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. For the theme working in components the mixin needs ":global".

I used [Zaratan's solution](https://www.zaratan.fr/next-refactor-theme-scss).