# React import .css according to process.env.REACT_APP_THEME

Tags: reactjs

I wish to change to React import source according to environment variable, such as:-

// App.js

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_THEME === 'Christmas'){
import 'css/Christmas/app.scss';
} else {
import 'css/Easter/app.scss';
}
```

or something like

```
import 'css/${process.env.REACT_APP_THEME}'/app.scss;
```

is it possible?

if not, must I use webpack?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, but not successful :( so I wish to explore the proper way if there is

Comment: This probably answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module