# How to import or require a js file dynamically depending on if it's development or production env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, electron

### Problem

I know that `ES6 imports` and `NODE require()` use static analysis and do not support dynamic paths. But how do we work around it? What's the solution?

My Electron app, during installation copies `shortcuts.js` file from development (project) folder `[project_dir]/public/resources` into the `[app_installation_dir]/resources` folder.

So the problem is:

- In development the app should import `../public/resources/shortcuts.js`
- In production the app should import `[app_installation_dir]/resources/shortcuts.js`

I cannot specify the "non-dynamic" path for production since I don't know in advance what `[app_installation_dir]` path is going to be.

### Code

I tried the following, but expectedly only the `else` brunch works:

```js
const shortcuts = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? require(`${process.resourcesPath}/shortcuts.js`).data
  : require(../public/resources/shortcuts.js`).data
```

After installing the app, in production, I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module [app_installation_dir]/resources/shortcuts.js
```

since, I guess, `require` doesn't see the dynamic path as something it can import (I checked, the file exists at this path).

I then converted the file from `module.exports` to `export default {}` and tried the following ES6 method but I get the same error:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const importPath = path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'shortcuts.js')
  import(importPath)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('IMPORT DATA', data)
    })
}
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  import('../public/resources/shortcuts.js')
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('IMPORT DATA', data)
    })
}
```

#### babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [  
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
  ]
}
```

#### Project created

```
vue create app-name
> selected [babel, eslint]


vue add electron-builder
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543835/10377254

Comment: @Jacob no, still the same error. I updated the question, showing what I did. Do I need to install some other babel preset for it to work?

Comment: @Rhayene thanks for the suggestion, but didn't help. I get the same error when I use `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`

Comment: @Rhayene sorry, I don't udnerstand the question. I never used REPL. But even if it's a problem with node's `require`, I don't understand why the following ES6 method doesn't work either: `import(importPath).then((data) => {})`. As I mentioned I changed the way file exports the data from `module.exports` / `require` to `export default {}` / `import()`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I can't see why the require method would not work assuming the path is absolute. If shortcuts.js contained data that could be exported as plain JSON, maybe an idea I would try is convert that file into json and use the file system to read it and parse it.

```
import fs from 'fs'

const shortcuts = JSON.parse(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? fs.readFileSync(`${process.resourcesPath}/shortcuts.json`).toString())
  : fs.readFileSync(`../public/resources/shortcuts.js`).toString()).data
```

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why it doesn't see it. I literally copy/paste the path from the error into the File Explorer and it opens the file. Maybe it's the way I export it? `shortcuts.js` looks like this `export default {  shortcut1: {key1: 'value1'} }`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I suppose I have no other choice than to use this method