# How to conditionally export values in a (CRA) React App

Tags: reactjs, mocking, conditional-rendering

In my React (v17) app I would like to render API handlers differently depending on whether there is an `process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE` defined.

So something in effect like

```js
if (process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE) {
  // use the actual API handler
  export { login, loginSilent, logout } from './api'
} else {
  // use the inline fake API handler
  export { login, loginSilent, logout } from './fake'
}
```

However trying that I get the error `Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`.

Is there a standard way to selectively use one file or the other like this?

**clarification**

What I'm looking for is a way for Webpack or Babel to conditionally render one export or the other, rather than leaving both options inline in the code.

**further clarification**

I've tried to use various babel plugins and webpack overrides (using customize-cra etc) but none of that worked terribly well and seemed to introduce more problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I conditionally import an ES6 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module)

Comment: alas no.  see clarification above

Answer (score 0):

Try to split out the logic to make sure export appear at the top level.

```
import {
  login as loginMock,
  loginSilent as loginSilentMock,
  logout as logoutMock,
} from "./fake";
import {
  login as loginApi,
  loginSilent as loginSilentApi,
  logout as logoutApi,
} from "./api";
const [login, loginSilent, logout] = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE
  ? [loginMock, loginSilentMock, logoutMock]
  : [loginApi, loginSilentApi, logoutApi];
export { login, loginSilent, logout };
```

Comment: This will have the effect of webpack bundling up both the fake and real APIs.  what I am after is not so much a conditional import as conditional code rendering by webpack or babel I think