# Import React on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a plain javascript website. I'm importing with webpack a react component and use it in the website.
The problem is the component only works if I import react(globally).
I only use this component once in a while so I only want to import react if needed.
I'm interested in such a thing:
`if(some_condition){ import react and import my component}`
How could I do this?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module

Answer (score 0):

You can do dynamic imports like this:

```js
(async () => {
  if (somethingIsTrue) {
    import('/modules/my-module.js')
      .then((module) => {
      // Do something with the module.
    });
  }
})();
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports).

```js
if (condition) {
  Promise.all([
    import("react-dom"),
    import("react"),
    import("path/to/component"),
  ])
    // if you use named export for component, just use name instead of `default`
    .then(([{ render }, { createElement }, { default: Component }]) => {
      // select element where you want to render
      let root = document.getElementById("root");
      // render your component
      render(createElement(Component), root);
    });
}
```