# How to dynamically import d3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I know that modules can normally be dynamically imported with the following syntax ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543835/6456163)):

```js
if (condition) {
    import('something')
    .then((something) => {
       console.log(something.something);
    });
}
```

However, the `d3` library has to be imported with this syntax, not the normal `import` syntax:

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

How do I combine the two of these to dynamically import the `d3` library in an ES6 environment?

Comment: [Some information on MDN which may help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only)

Comment: Thanks a ton, guess I completely missed that part until you pointed it out again @Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Andy, I discovered that my desired behavior is already happening behind the scenes!

> It returns a promise which fulfills to an object containing all exports from `moduleName`, with the same shape as a namespace import (`import * as name from moduleName`): a [sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isSealed) object with [`null` prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#null-prototype_objects).

Hope this can help someone else, cheers!